# Loops that produce different values for each item in list

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a loop that goes through a list of countries in a list and I want to find the total from each one and put it as a new object with the country name. So I want a list at the end: australia_total, brazil_total, etc which has the total number for each country.

The last line in the code is the one that doesn't work

```
for c in countrylist:
  country = data[data.country == c]
  
  pivotcountry = country.pivot_table(['new_cases','new_deaths'], index='week', aggfunc='sum', margins=False)
  pivotcountry.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
  {c}_total = pivotcountry.new_cases.iloc[-1]
```

Comment: `country = data[data.country == c]` this means country = data[False] or data[True] depending on whether data.country is equal to the c in the list. What did you want to do here?

Comment: That bit makes a new dataframe for each country in my list, exludes data from all the other countries

Comment: Does it produce an error? Is the dictionary not updated? Please provide more information.

Comment: Creating a new key in a dict is: `c['_total'] = pivotcountry.new_cases.iloc[-1]`

Comment: I get the error -  'str' object does not support item assignment for:

c['_total'] = pivotcountry.new_cases.iloc[-1]

Comment: My end result is I want totals for each country and number of cases in the last week. The original data is from the below. My loop goes through each country and creates weekly pivot tables for each country

https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the totals to appear in a new DataFrame then you'll need to add a new row for each time around the loop:

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv(r"WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv", skipinitialspace=True)

countrylist = data.Country.unique()

out_columns = ['Country', 'Total_cases', 'Total_deaths']
out_data = pandas.DataFrame(columns=out_columns)

for c in countrylist:
  country = data[data.Country == c]

  case_total = country['New_cases'].sum()
  deaths_total = country['New_deaths'].sum()
  out_data = out_data.append(pandas.DataFrame([[c, case_total, deaths_total]], columns=out_columns))

print(out_data)
```

Gives:

```
                               Country Total_cases Total_deaths
0                          Afghanistan       34451         1010
0                              Albania        3571           95
0                              Algeria       19195         1011
0                              Andorra         855           52
0                               Angola         506           26
..                                 ...         ...          ...
0   Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)        9178           85
0                             Viet Nam         372            0
0                                Yemen        1469          418
0                               Zambia        1895           42
0                             Zimbabwe         985           18

[216 rows x 3 columns]
```

But if you genuinely want a Python variable for each country, then you can use the `locals()` dictionary:

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv(r"WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv", skipinitialspace=True)

countrylist = data.Country.unique()

for c in countrylist:
  country = data[data.Country == c]

  case_total = country['New_cases'].sum()
  locals()['%s_total' % (c.lower())] = case_total

print("Australia: %s" % australia_total)
print("Germany: %s" % germany_total)
```

However I wouldn't recommend using `locals()` to set new variables as it's not obvious to someone reading the code that new variable names are being created without using the traditional `foo = 123` assignment statement.